# Redirect all post into some category to url without category

Tags: redirect

I need to redirect about 200 post into category "ricette","svezzamento" and "alimentazione" to url without category. I have this code but not work.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');

function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {

global $post;
$catArray = ['ricette','svezzamento','alimentazione'];
if (is_single($post->ID) && has_category($catArray, $post){ 

    $new_url = "https://www.example.com/{$post->post_name}/";
    wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: are those url 'working'? why not use htaccess?

Comment: I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your URLs are of the form `/<category>/<post-name>/` (trailing slash optional) then an `.htaccess` only solution would look something like the following, at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Remove some categories from the URL
RewriteRule ^(ricette|svezzamento|alimentazione)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2/ [R=301,L]
```

The `$2` backreference (in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*) matches the `<post-name>` from the requested URL.

It is preferable to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects in order to avoid potential caching issues.

> `https://www.example.com/la-crescita/ricette/name-post` and I need go to `https://www.example.com/name-post`
>
> yes "la-crescita" is the first category and "ricette" is the subcategory of "la-crescita". File .htaccess is in the root of WordPress

If `/la-crescita` is always the main *category* and "ricette", "svezzamento" and "alimentazione" and *subcategories* of this main category then you need to modify the above directive to include the *category*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^la-crescita/(ricette|svezzamento|alimentazione)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your .htaccess not work

Comment: Please give an example of the URL you are trying to redirect from/to. (And make sure your browser cache is cleared, as any erroneous 301 redirects will have been cached by the browser.)

Comment: https://www.domain.it/la-crescita/ricette/name-post/ and I need go to https://www.domain.it/name-post/

Comment: What is the `/la-crescita` part of the URL? Where is the `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: yes "la-crescita" is the first category and "ricette" is the subcategory of "la-crescita". File .htaccess is in the root of WordPress

Comment: Mrwhite have you got some news for me?

Comment: So, "la-crescita" is always the parent category that needs to be matched? I've updated my answer.

Comment: now work perfectly, thanx!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, then please mark it as "accepted" (tick/checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update site permalink structure from "/%category%/%postname%/" to "/%postname%/".

To update the permalinks Goto: Settings > Permalink

Comment: Although it seems the OP only wants to redirect a select few categories, not everything?